# .gitignore .js files made from TypeScript

Tags: git, gitignore

I Have the following files:

- ActiveTask.ts
- ActiveTask.js
- Controller.ts
- Controller.js
- _config.js
- otherFile.js

And I want to commit only:

- ActiveTask.ts
- Controller.ts
- _config.js
- otherFile.js

How to ignore .js files that are the same name as the .ts files?

Answer (score 13):

1. Change the `outDir` entry of your `tsconfig.json` file. This is conventionally called `build` but you can name it whatever you'd like.

```json
// tsconfig.json (mine is in the root directory of my project)
{
    "compilerOptions": {  
      ...
      "outDir": "myAwesomeSuperCoolBuildDirectoryThatIPromiseToChangeAndNotJustCopyBlindlyFromStackOverflowBecauseThatWouldBeBad",  
      "sourceMap": true,  
      ...
    }
}
```

2. Add `outDir` followed by a `forward slash --> /`  to your `.gitignore` file

```
// .gitignore (mine is in the root directory of my project)
myAwesomeSuperCoolBuildDirectoryThatIPromiseToChangeAndNotJustCopyBlindlyFromStackOverflowBecauseThatWouldBeBad/
```

3. Delete  old `js.map` and `js` files generated by TypeScript and build them again. This time, they will be built in the specified directory and will be ignored by git.

Answer (score 1):

For your **particular** case, I suggest:

In `.gitignore`

```
*.js
!_*.js
```

This will ignore all js files except what starting with underscore.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, but the other .js files I want to commit are not always starting with underscore.

Comment: Then, I suggest that put all `js` files *generated* from `ts` files and `ts` files into one directory. And ignore that directory.

Comment: Second suggestion is, get filenames with `ls *.ts` or `dir *.ts` then, remove extension (`.ts`). And append `.js` and write into `.gitignore`. This should be executed whenever there are new or renamed files.

Comment: Thanks, I did your first suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, try `dir_to_be_ignored/*.js`

Comment: @jeon I've just pulled out Jeon's recommendation into it's own answer here if you want to upvote for visibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804969/2441420 It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I found this working for me:

```
/FrontendApp/src/*/**/*.js
/FrontendApp/src/*/**/*.map
```

This excluded all js and map files from the /FrontendApp/src and its subfolders.